# What exactly is a vertex attribute?

Tags: opengl

I am new to opengl so I got confused about the terminology of vertex attributes and vertex. I wonder if someone could clarify for what exactly is a vertex attribute and how is it differ from a vertex.

Also, can you explain to me what does vertex attributes have to do with shaders?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A vertex attribute is an input variable to a shader that is supplied with per-vertex data. In OpenGL core profile, they are specified as `in` variables in a vertex shader and are backed by a `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`. These variable can contain, for example, positions, normals or texture coordinates.

A vertex is the combination of all the vertex attributes that belong together.

Comment: Is an input variable to a shader that is per-instance data NOT a vertex attribute?